# ActiveRecord multiple custom length validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model, rails-activerecord

I have an `Address` model and I need to validate the `:zipcode` length depending on the `:country`.

For example:

- If `:country == 'us'`, maximum `:zipcode` length should be `5`.
- If `:country == 'br'`, maximum `:zipcode` length should be `8`.

And so on...

I'm running Ruby on Rails 4.2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  ZIP_CODE_VALIDATION = { 'us' => 5, 'br' => 8 }.freeze                 

  validate :zip_code_by_country

  def max_length
    ZIP_CODE_VALIDATION[country]
  end

  def zip_code_by_country      
    return unless zipcode.length > max_length
    errors.add(:zipcode, "can't be greater than #{max_length}")
  end
end
```